# PowerShell New-Item Positional Parameter Oddities

Tags: powershell

Given the Microsoft documentation for PowerShell, I can see no reason why the following code should fail with the given error. Then again, PowerShell can fail when a script just gets too long. All the paths are double-quote strings.

```
##### ALGORITHM Take in keystore path, make a backup in an adjacent directory
$ksPath = $java_store_path.Substring(0, $java_store_path.LastIndexOf('\') + 1)
$backupPath = $ksPath + "backups"
New-Item $backupPath PowerShell -type directory -force
```

**New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'PowerShell'.**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx

```
New-Item c:\scripts\Windows PowerShell -type directory
```

If that's valid, mine should be too. I'm running on Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example on that page is just plain wrong. It seems they meant to refer to the path `C:\Scripts\WindowsPowerShell` or they forgot to quote the directory with spaces in it.

So it should have been one of these:

```
New-Item c:\scripts\WindowsPowerShell -type directory
New-Item 'c:\scripts\Windows PowerShell' -type directory
New-Item "c:\scripts\Windows PowerShell" -type directory
```

Ask yourself, what would `PowerShell` alone have been referring to? What parameter would it have corresponded to?

---

Edit: as the commenters have pointed out, the example was supposed to show the `nameSet` parameters, where a separate `-Path` and `-Name` are specified, and purportedly `PowerShell` was supposed to be a value to the `-Name` parameter. That does look correct. The reason the example didn't work (and yours as well), is because the `-Name` parameter cannot be specified positionally, which you can see in the MSDN article I linked to below, and in the built-in help:

> ```
> Type: String
> Parameter Sets: nameSet
> Aliases: 
>
> Required: True
> Position: Named
> Default value: None
> Accept pipeline input: True (ByPropertyName)
> Accept wildcard characters: False
> ```

In that case, their example should have been something like these:

```
New-Item c:\scripts\Windows -Name PowerShell -type directory
New-Item -Path c:\scripts\Windows -Name PowerShell -type directory
```

So reiterating, named parameters would have worked here, and would have avoided confusion.

---

Generally, you shouldn't be using positional parameters in scripts, unless they're extremely clear (and even then, I'd recommend avoiding).

Using named parameters would have made this easier to figure out. And tab-completion helps with filling in the parameter names and in completing paths (usually with proper quoting too).

I think you should change yours to:

```
New-Item -Path $backupPath -Type Directory -Force
```

And looking over that technet article, it's really not so good. The [MSDN article on New-Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is better, and this is the information you should see when running `Get-Help New-Item` as well.

---

Side question:

> Then again, PowerShell can fail when a script just gets too long.

*What?*

Comment: I'm not joking. We have a 5000-line PS monolith that does server setup, config, and maintenance task scheduling. It broke because it got to be too big. Parameters just fall through functions into each other's positions for no transparent reason, and we used LLVM's static analysis tools to validate the dataflows as-written. After 5400 lines it just falls apart on its own. We're in the process of breaking it down into multiple scriptlets.

Comment: Agreed. The example specifically states that it will create a new folder named `Windows PowerShell` within the `C:\Scripts` folder.

Comment: @andyb looking further I agree with you and (now deleted) other comment(s), though I think it only further makes the point that positional parameters can be confusing. I've edited to clarify. Thanks!